# How to get user role(student/teacher)

Tags: google-classroom

How can I get user role(student/teacher) using google classroom api OR if not possible to get user role from google API then how can we manage user in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method to get the role in Classroom API yet. But, they do have [Manage Teachers and Students](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users) where you can:

- [Add or remove teachers](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users#add_or_remove_teachers)
- [Enroll or remove students](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users#enroll_or_remove_students)
- [Retrieve a user's courses](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users#user-courses)
- [Retrieve a user's profile](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users#retrieve_a_users_profile)

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop over the course teachers and check if your user is one of them.

In PHP -

```
function isUserTeacher($userIdToCheck, $courseId)
{
    $teachers = (new Google_Service_Classroom($client))->courses_teachers->listCoursesTeachers($courseId);
    foreach ($teachers->getTeachers() as $teacher) {
        if($teacher->getUserId() == $userIdToCheck)
            return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```